# Is it worth rebuilding a broken front wheel

Tags: road-bike, maintenance, wheels

Hit a pretty bad pothole at the weekend which caused the rim of my front wheel to shatter into 4 peices.
The hub is still intact and appears fine. Is it worth buying a new rim and spokes and rebuilding? The wheel is a Mavic Ksyrium Pro SL.

Comment: Sounds dramatic -- I hope you're OK!

Comment: It was dramatic  I'm fine though

Comment: If you do it yourself (not a simple task) you MIGHT come out ahead.

Comment: Does insurance cover your accident at all?  If so, they may claim ownership of the parts.

Comment: No. Insurance doesn't cover accidental damage. I'm currently upgrading so that it does in future. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to cost it out, as it pretty much comes down to the dollars cents.

With a wheel at that price point its worth considering a rebuild, presuming you have a good wheel builder at your LBS. If you buy a new wheel, ensure the cost includes having the new wheel tuned up by the LBS. (If you not buying through a shop, add the cost having a shop tune it when it arrives).

Unless the hub has low miles, consider a full service with new bearings, or at least put the cost of this into the rebuild of the wheel.

In terms of if its worth it, you may decide reusing the hub rather than adding it to a landfill adds to the worth of a rebuild over a new wheel.

Comment: The hub could also be reused as part of a workstand, or a trailer hitch.   The hidden cost of a rebuild is in the spokes - its likely the old ones have been stressed and bent, and a full set of spokes adds up even when they're only a few dollars each.

Comment: Thanks. A set of spokes will cost me £25 and a rim £40. £65 Vs £300 for a new wheel.

Comment: If you are building it up  yourself it makes a lot of sense to rebuild. I have no idea what a good wheel builder charges, I imagine its not cheap.